# Installing Postgresql: postmaster not found

Tags: installation, postgresql

I'm trying to get a postgesql server running (most recent version). I downloaded the source, and it compiled fine. I also created a user postgresql and let that user own /usr/local/pgsql/data and such. I followed the installation procedure on the website of postgresql.

However, the system now can't find the postmaster program, necessary to start the server (not on my account, but also not on the special created postgres account). Apt-get install also can't find a program called postmaster, so I assumed it was part of postgress.

Clearly I did or understood something wrong, can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the postgresql binaries to the PATH of the postgresql user (and other users) who need to use them; e.g. for bash

su - postgresql

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin

If you can then use the postgresql commands, you'll want to bake the change into the users' profiles (a script in /etc/profile.d/ or as appropriate to your *ix flavour).